# Proper way to access third party libs such as D3 in Ember CLI?

Tags: ember-cli

Here is how I've done:

```
bower install d3 --save
```

then added to `Broccoli.js`:

```
app.import('bower_components/d3/d3.js');
```

then in my view, added:

```
import d3 from 'bower_components/d3/d3';
```

and attempted to use it.

This causes an issue when launching the app. In devtools I see this error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined  vendor.js:40
Module   vendor.js:52
define   vendor.js:88532
(anonymous function)   vendor.js:88534
(anonymous function)
```

So I'm guessing that I'm including it the wrong way.

I'm trying to avoid adding stuff to .jshintrc and making all import explicit instead, but no luck so far. So I tried that too:

Don't import d3 in my module, and instead just add d3 to jshint's `predef`. No luck either, same issue.

How have you guys been doing this?

Thanks!

Comment: This is absolutely not off topic. And the solution is very useful for anyone finding these errors.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had the wrong loader.js version installed. Should be 1.0.1, and I had 2.1.1. Now everything works!